# Axios doesn't return anything

Tags: typescript, axios

It's my first javascript real project. I'm coding a healthcheck for some environments, in which must be validated through a specific endpoint. Everything is going well so far, except for the following:

In both scenarios (success or error), I can't get the status code back through the return statement.

basically:

```
environment.applications.forEach(async (app) => {
            app.status = await getStatus("https://something.com/healthcheck");
        });

private async getStatus(url: string): Promise<number> {
    return await this.get(url)
        .then((response) => {
           console.log(`Success in the url ${response}`);
           return response.status;
        }, (error) => {
            console.log(`Error in the url ${error.config.url}: ${error}`);
            return error.response.status;
        });
}
```

The `console.log('Success in the url ${response}');` never executes and never returns anything.

The `console.log('Error in the url ${error.config.url}: ${error}');` executes always in case of error (One endpoint doesn't exist on purpose), an never returns anything too.

What i'm doing wrong? I Know that the `catch()` block usually throws and error, but It doesn't seems to be the case.

the `this.get()` is a implementation of axios's get method:

```
public get<T, R = AxiosResponse<T>>(url: string, config?: AxiosRequestConfig): Promise<R> {
    return this.get (url, config);
}
```

Thank you all.

Comment: You need to show what 'this' is and how and where you are calling this function

Comment: Can you show the code that calls this `getStatus()` function? Async is difficult and easy to forget to decode the promise.

Comment: Code updated, my friends.

Answer (score 1):

Throw out your then().  You are already using async, that's great, it nicely replaces the then() and should help you find the issue.

```
private async getStatus(url: string): Promise<number> {
 try {
   const response = await this.get(url)
   console.log(`Success in the url ${response}`);
   return response.status;
 } catch (err) {
   console.error(`Error in the url ${url}: ${err}`);
   throw err  
 }
```

This won't solve your issue but improve your code so you can easily solve more issues.
Curious if the "error.config.url" caused a null pointer in your error handler, hiding your error from you.